# What are (dis)advantages running POE (Perl object environment) under Windows?

Tags: perl, poe

I need to build a production critical system for networking using the [POE](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE/) module under Windows system.

As I see from some source in the Internet that POE is not behaved well under Windows, could someone give feedback for bad or good about the usage of POE framework under Windows?

Comment: Add a link to that "some source".